# BATCH: goto EOF if variable contains a word

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch script and it has a variable '%4' and it's random file names but sometimes it has names like:

```
some.thing.here.mp3
some.other.thing.mp3
and.another.mp3
and.some.file.mp3
```

and i want to have it goto EOF if the file name contains the word 'some' (so all but the third file..)

i have this so far but it's not working

```
IF /I "%4"=="some" GOTO EOF
```

Comment: Post your batch file so far. It's easier to test that way. I'm guessing you just need to use find or findstr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "%4" | find /i "some" >nul 2>&1 && GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: as a side question can i include multiple words? like "someORotherORfoobar"?

Comment: Yes, but `find`  finds every individual word.

Comment: So put the search pattern in a variable `set "var=some"`  `echo "%4" | find /i "%var%"`

Comment: Example: `echo "%4" | findstr /i "some test"`, for more words you should use `findstr`.

Comment: i've come across a problem with this i'm using the below code to find the word 'test' in %4 (which is normally file names like in my first post) but when changing the code to %5 (which is a folders full path eg. "c:\temp\some.test.folder") it's not picking it up.. will this code not work for folders like it does for files?

    echo "%~5" | find /i "test" >nul 2>&1 && GOTO end

Comment: hmm my last comment is all screwed up.. i can't use line breaks or indents for the code? :/

Comment: Yes, you can use indents. What do you mean with line breaks? %5 can't contain a line break ....

Comment: when i said 'i can't use line breaks or indents for the code' i mean the COMMENT i made NOT my code in question (like for example i can't press enter for a new line as it'll just save the comment) and nor can i format my code but again my problem persists.. here's a readable version: http://tinyurl.com/blt79sm

Comment: after a bit of testing yes the command is working it's the next part involving the move command that is failing as i'm getting an 'access denied' error... think it's best to make a new thread about this.. thanks for the help :)

Comment: No, it works for me, please see [here](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/wnw0eba8/snap112.gif) and [here](http://pastebin.com/JCqzeB30).
And yes, in comments you can't make "enter", you can "shift-enter", but it will not be seen.

Comment: yes i know that's working but again the problem is with the next part of the script: http://tinyurl.com/bld488u (i tried to make a new thread about this but it won't let me)

Comment: made a topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502283/how-do-i-fix-access-denied-with-the-move-command-in-windows-7