# how do i fix: 'access denied' with the move command in windows 7?

Tags: batch-file, move

Hi there i'm using the windows 7 'move' command like so:

```
move /Y "C:\old.sub.folder\folder.i.want.to.move" "F:\new.sub.folder\folder.i.want.to.move"
```

and i keep getting an 'accessed denied' error yet i have full permissions and the folder i'm trying to move isn't open or being uses?

a random example trying to move one empty folder to another: http://puu.sh/2Rx6b.png

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: try run bat file as Administrator

Comment: this is a year old topic and i don't run windows anymore but thanks for trying :)

Comment: lol :-D I have not looked at the date :-)

Answer (score 22):

Or you could try `robocopy` with `/MOVE` argument:

```
robocopy C:\old\folder F:\new\folder /E /MOVE
```

Comment: Does robocopy /move  move the files the same way the move command or explorer does, or does it copy and then delete? I get access denied when using os.system in python with the move command (although I think Python can move files without having to run system commands). I changed it to robocopy and it's taking a while.

Comment: no, it doesn't. `move` doesn't touch the file itself, it only changes the file allocation table. This is why `move` can't move a file to another drive. Any move to another drive *must* make a copy

Comment: does it delete each file after copying, or deletes them all after finish ? if 2nd, is with cmd a way to achieve 1st, without cmd loop ?

Answer (score 5):

Syntax is:

```
MOVE [/Y| /-Y] [Drive:][Path]Folder1 Folder2
```

That means, you can rename one folder, but you cannot "move" contents to another drive.

I'm afraid, you have to copy your source-folder to the destination-folder (xcopy) and then delete the source-folder

Comment: i don't understand though why can the move command move files but not folders? isn't there a command to move the folder? i don't mind using a separate exe for this if need be :)

Comment: @Stephan copy/delete takes *ages* when you're moving many gig. It also wastes your hard drives life with the *completely* unnecessary duplicate data. To top it off, it probably fragments your filesystem.

Comment: @jozxyqk: the OP wants to move from C: to F:. I don't know how to to that without transferring the data.

Comment: @Stephan aah, fair point. I've just hit this issue and want to move on the same drive.

Comment: @jozxyqk: Then `move` is the right way to do it for you. It only changes FAT-Entries without moving the files. (that's why it don't work from one drive to another)

Comment: @Stephan That's exactly what I'm after but I'm having some [issues replacing/merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588225/how-do-you-merge-two-directories-or-move-with-replace-from-the-windows-command) when folder names match

Comment: I am moving files to the same drive and getting this error. I tried robocopy as suggested by Razvan and not sure if that's moving or copying and deleting.

Answer (score -1):

Best way for any access related issue is :
Add a new principal "Everyone", give complete access and then enable inheritance.
Kaboom !!! all access issues resolved/.

Steps:

1. Go to properties of file > Security tab > Advanced Button.
2. Under Permissions tab> Add > Select a principal > Type "Everyone" > Click "Check Names" button > Everyone written on object name will be recognized> CLick "ok".
   Please attach below reference,
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFos5.png)
3. select all "Basic Permissions"
4. Click "OK"
5. Select "Enable Inheritance" on "Advanced Security Settings>Permissions"