# Acces denied when moving folder to usb drive

Tags: c++

when I try to move the "HelloWorld" folder to an usb drive it says acces denied in the command line

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char src[50],dest[50],cmd[100],penPath[1];
  
  cout<<"\nENTER LETTER OF THE FLASH MEMORY (raw letter.  E.g: I,H,F,...): ";
  cin>>penPath;

  strcpy(src,"%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\HelloWorld");
  strcpy(dest,penPath);
  strcat(dest,":\\");
 
  strcpy(cmd,"move ");
  strcat(cmd,src);                                          
  strcat(cmd," ");
  strcat(cmd,dest);
  system(cmd);
  return 0;
}
```

I think that the problem its related to the usb path that is given, but i dont know how to solve

Comment: What's happening if you do that in a CMD terminal manually? That  problem has barely to do with your c++ code, but exactly what the error message says: You don't have access rights for the target folder. Try running your program jwith admin privileges.

Comment: Don't waste your time with `system`. You're running a program that runs another program when you could do the deed directly. Since this is a Windows PC, [use `MoveFileExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this path "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\HelloWorld" it seems like you are running this on Windows.

This question has been answered here: [how do i fix: 'access denied' with the move command in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502283/how-do-i-fix-access-denied-with-the-move-command-in-windows-7/37047060)

The move command cannot move folders to another drive, you will have to use the robocopy command instead.

Your command should be something like this:

```
robocopy %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\HelloWorld F:\ /E /MOVE
```

where F is replaced by whatever drive letter is entered. It seems like you have no trouble concatenating strings, so I'll let you do it.

the `/E` flag tells robocopy to copy all subdirectories and the `/MOVE` flag tells it to delete the original after copying it to the new location.